# trying to display the input values but nothing shows up with no error in console reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to display the input values from the following form but nothing appears, what i did is: i wrote the code and i fixed each error appears immediately. i thought that will prevent any future problems but it didnt work. it ended up without any error in the console + not displaying the input values

i have looked multiple websites but none of them has helped me

here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Users(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState();
  const [active, setActive] = useState();
  const [currentDepartment, setCurrentDepartment] = useState("");
  const { register, option } = useForm();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
  };
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.setData((prev) => prev.concat({ username, name, surname, active }));
  }

  let password = "MyPA55w()rd";
  let upper_count = 0;
  let lower_count = 0;
  let number_count = 0;
  let symbol_count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    let c = password.charAt(i);

    if ("A" <= c && c <= "Z") {
      upper_count += 1;
    } else if ("a" <= c && c <= "z") {
      lower_count += 1;
    } else if ("0" <= c && c <= "9") {
      number_count += 1;
    } else {
      symbol_count += 1;
    }
  }

  return (
    <form>
      User Name
      <input
        defaultValue={username}
        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="username"
        name="username"
        ref={register}
      />
      <br />
      Name
      <input
        defaultValue={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        name="name"
        ref={register}
      />
      <br />
      Surname
      <input
        defaultValue={surname}
        onChange={(e) => setSurname(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="surname"
        name="surname"
        ref={register}
      />
      <br />
      Choose Your Department
      <select defaultValue={currentDepartment}>
        <option value="N/A">Choose Your Department</option>
        <option value="1">Electrical Engineering</option>
        <option value="2">Mechanical Engineering</option>
        <option value="3">Chemical Engineering</option>
        <option value="4">Computer Sciense and Engineering</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      Password
      <input
        defaultValue="{password}"
        type="password"
        placeholder="password"
        name="password"
        ref={register({
          required: true,
          minLength: 8,
          maxLength: 16,
        })}
      />
      <br />
      Profile Picture
      <input type="file" />
      <br />
      Email
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="Email" ref={register} />
      <br />
      Day of Start
      <input
        type="date"
        placeholder="dateOfStart"
        name="date of start"
        ref={register}
      />
      <br />
      Birthday
      <input
        defaultValue="Birthday"
        type="date"
        placeholder="Birthday"
        name="Birthday"
        ref={register}
      />
      <br />
      is Active
      <input
        defaultValue={active}
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={(e) => setActive(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onSubmit={handleSubmit}> Submit </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Users;
```

there was some errors appearing but i fixed all of them
any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If my answer is useful plz check it, I will be happy :)

Answer (score 1):

The function handleChange is not used in jour JSX, and you have to bind every input with its state value like this value={stateInput} and bind also the event onChange with the function handleChange:

Example:

```
 const handleUserNameChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value); //username value
    setUsername(e.target.value);
};

    
  <input
    value={username}
    defaultValue={username}
    onChange={handleUserNameChange}
    type="text"
    placeholder="username"
    name="username"
    ref={register}
/>;
```

And repeat the same thing for other inputs.

Comment: thank u for your respone
but shall i do it for every input the same way?
isnt there any shorten way?

Comment: hey again i did exactly as u mentioned but i got the following errors:
index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: index.js:1 Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.